# Syntax error for ajax call with url as a variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

The `url` line is giving me a syntax error when I am trying to pass a variable to it. Not sure why - does it need to be a hard coded url?

```
function initMicrosite(){
    var JSON_url = $('#micrositeInit').data('JSON');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: JSON_url; //Syntax error here
        data: {},
        success: function(data){
            JSON_data = data;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Seriously? A downvote and a vote to close?  - legitimate SO question about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url: JSON_url; //Syntax error here
```

should become:

```
url: JSON_url, //No more syntax errors here
```

Notice the `,` vs `;`. Basically the `,` allows you to define other properties in a javascript object whereas the `;` indicates the end of a statement.

Comment: LOL duh - been a long day. Thanks.